# HTML: is it better to code the entire image address, or /images

Tags: html, performance, seo, load-time

Example A:

```
<div id="content-box">
    <div class="content-box-inner">
    Title
        <br/>
        <a href="www.google.com"><div class="cb-item"><img src="http://www.hellothere.com/images/image.jpg"/> Hello There</div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example B:

```
<div id="content-box">
    <div class="content-box-inner">
    Title
        <br/>
        <a href="www.google.com"><div class="cb-item"><img src="/images/image.jpg"/> Hello There</div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is either way specifically better? Does using only /images make the page load faster? is having the entire link better for SEO?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use relative addressing (your **Example B**), because you can more easily move your site from dev to test to production servers without having to find and change a bunch of links.

Always use relative addressing ... you never know when you will need to change the website prefix!

Answer (score 0):

It's smart to use **Example B** if you are writing a big code. But it does not makes the page load slower if you are using **Example A**
Also if you move you website it keeps finding the image!

**EDIT:**

Also; you have to use `<a href="http://www.google.com">Link</a>` to make it work. Else it sends you to `yourwebsite.com/www.google.com`